# jQuery.ajax - submit all elements in form without manually entering them

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I would like to use jQuery.ajax to submit a form using POST without having to specify everything manually in the "data: " part.

This is what I don't want:

```
data:   "username=" + document.getElementById("username").value + 
    "&email=" + document.getElementById("email").value,
```

Is there a way to just have it include alla elements with their values from an entire FORM field? This form is generated dynamically so it would save me a lot of time!

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Use [serialize method](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/serialize).

```
data :   $("form").serialize()
```

Comment: Don't forget to give each input element a name.

Comment: Use the `:input` selector: `$("#form :input").serialize()`

Comment: holy cow, why is that so hard to find! beautiful.

Answer (score 10):

Look at http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/serialize.

That would make the following example:

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        data: $("form").serialize(),
        ...rest
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.serialize()` method to send entire form data in jQuery Ajax.

```
data:$('#formID').serialize()
```

Example script can be found from here - [How to send entire form data in jQuery Ajax](http://www.codexworld.com/how-to-guides/send-entire-form-data-jquery-ajax/)